# Compile c program for android

Tags: android, c, linux, adb

I have hello world program written in C,I'm compiling it using

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc hello.c -o hello
```

and running it by pushing it to android device using adb

```
adb push hello /system
adb shell chmod 777 /system/hello
```

after that I'm trying to run hello binary in adb shell  but it says

```
./hello
/system/bin/sh: ./hello: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help me please?

Hello world program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it seems that you are not in the correct directory

Comment: Is your device rooted

Comment: @Manül:I'm in correct path also have tried with absolute path also

Answer (score 1):

That happens when your program has a dependency on a missing library. Is your build environment correctly set up to use android bionic libc?

Try to push your binary to /system/bin instead of /system. And call your binary without the ./ prefix.

Try to change the permissions to sunbathing more restrictive like 744 or 755.

If it still does not make it, have a look to this thread:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/73491/no-such-file-or-directory-for-existing-executable